# how: use the set function to change variable permanently. so if i run the program again the values are replaced

Tags: java, class, object, methods

```
public class Damascus{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    AssaultRifles fal = new AssaultRifles("FAL",99,621,45,160,75,25,45,180,5,110,23);

switch (secondChoice) {
          case 'n':
          changeS = input.nextLine();
          fal.setName(changeS);
          System.out.println("Name changed to: "+fal.getName);
          break;
//i want the change to be there when i run the program again
```

Comment: sorry if the question is weird, im still trying to get the hang of stack overflow.

Comment: If you want any data persist through restart of your program, you need to save it into a file.

Comment: Check the link I gave at the top to see if it answers your question.